# Equality operator not working inside SwiftUI ForEach

Tags: swift, swiftui, foreach, conditional-operator, swiftui-foreach

I have a ForEach loop that needs to have either a true or false passed into the custom view it generates, based on if it's the first iteration of the ForEach loop or not. I've tried using a ternary operator as seen below, and also a classic if-else, but it seems like if I use the equality (==) operator to compare 'card' to cards.first, the code doesn't compile...

```
struct CustomGeneratedView: View {
  private var cards: [CustomStruct] = [object1, object2, object3, object4,...]
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      ForEach(cards.prefix(3).sorted(by: { $0.id > $1.id }), id: \.self) { card in
        CardView(firstCard: card == cards.first) // this is the problem line, not sure how to fix it...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The CustomStruct looks something like this:

```
struct CustomStruct: Hashable, Equatable {
    var id: Int
    let type: CustomStruct2 //this also conforms to equatable
    var title: String?
    var rated: CustomStruct3? //this also conforms to equatable
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to make `CustomStruct` conform to `Equatable`?

Comment: By the way, `card == cards.first ? true : false` doesn't make any sense to write. You're taking the boolean (`card == cards.first`), returning true if it's true, and false if it's false. That's just equivalent to the original of the original boolean.

Comment: @Alexander Adding equatable to to the CustomStruct didn't work--I'm just getting a 'Compiler unable type-check this expression in a reasonable amount of time at the top of the view...

Comment: Well it did, it just lead to another problem. You should extract the  `cards.prefix(3).sorted(by: { $0.id > $1.id })` expression. Not only because type-checking it is costly, but because you don't want to be resorting and prefixing on every render of your view.

Comment: I see, I'll do that as well--thanks. I think the issue here is something to do with 'cards'. I'm returning it outside of the body with a switch case that applies different filters--that's causing some odd behavior @Alexander

Comment: "I'm returning it outside of the body with a switch case" What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `cards.first` returns a optional. So try something like this, works well for me:

```
ForEach(cards.prefix(3).sorted(by: { $0.id > $1.id }), id: \.self) { card in
    CardView(firstCard: (cards.first == nil ? false : card == cards.first!))
}
```

Comment: did my answer not work for you? Works very well for me.